# make var value persistent, regardless interval

Tags: javascript, setinterval, var

Here is my javascript code:

```
window.setInterval(run, 1000);
var oldprice = 1;

function run(){
    var price = $('#s3').text();
    if(price > oldprice){
        console.log("price gone up");
        var oldprice = price;
    }
    if(price == oldprice){
        console.log("price remains");
    }
    if(price < oldprice){
        console.log("price dropped");
        var oldprice = price;
    }
}
```

How can I make the value of `oldprice` persistent, so that it is remembered?

Comment: don't re-create the variable with `var oldprice` inside `run()` function. Just assign value to it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Inside your `run()`, change this:

```
var oldprice = price;
```

to this

```
oldprice = price;
```

You were declaring a new variable (with **local scope**), when you wanted to access the one with **global scope**.

**The local one shadows the global variable.**

On other words, it doesn't matter they have the same name, they are not the same. They are placed in different memory cells!

Your code has the same behaviour as this code:

```
window.setInterval(run, 1000);
var oldprice = 1;

function run(){
    var price = $('#s3').text();
    if(price > oldprice){
        console.log("price gone up");
        var local_oldprice = price;
    }
    if(price == local_oldprice){
        console.log("price remains");
    }
    if(price < local_oldprice){
        console.log("price dropped");
        var local_oldprice = price;
    }
}
```

A general tip, when using global variables in `JavaScript` is to have their names as:

`global_oldprice`

instead of:

`oldprice`

In other words adding the `global_` in the name of the variable.

Another approach is to have a global array, which his name had the *global* word included and the global variables are cells of the array.

With that approach, your global variables would be called as:

`globalVars[i]`

But of course this also depends on personal taste.

Answer (score 4):

Don't create a **locally scoped** variable of the same name inside the function

```
var oldprice = price;
```

Remove the `var`